# Trouble communicating between Client/Server C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, client-server, chat

I have a client(c++) / server(c) program and currently I'm having difficulty communicating between them (I can't see what the client says on the server and vice versa). Also I am trying have this project multi-threaded, or at least accept multiple connections from clients. All help is greatly appreciated here is the code pertaining to chatting, you can view it in its entirety [here](http://pastebin.com/AQb6rfYX)

**client:**

```
    recv(sockfd , server_reply , 2000 , 0);

    puts("Enter message :"); // asking for password
    scanf("%s" , message);
    send(sockfd , message , strlen(message) , 0);

    recv(sockfd, server_reply, 2000, 0);
    //Receive a reply from the server
    if( recv(sockfd , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

while( (read_size = recv(nsockfd , server_reply , 4000 , 0)) != 0)
  {

    puts("Enter message :"); // asking for password
    scanf("%s" , message);
    send(sockfd , message , strlen(message) , 0);

    recv(sockfd, server_reply, 2000, 0);


  }
```

Server

```
      char client_address[90];
    sprintf(client_address, "Welcome %s", inet_ntoa(addr_remote.sin_addr));

    char welc_msg[90] = "Welcome %s";
    char friend_msg[50] = "Hello little friend \n";
    char username[30] = "Enter user:";
    char pass[30] = "Enter pass: ";

    write(nsockfd , client_address , strlen(client_address)); // attempting to send client "Hello, (their ip address)"
    read_size = recv(nsockfd , client_message , 4000 , 0);

    read_size = recv(nsockfd , client_message , 4000 , 0);
printf( "%s", client_message);
printf( "\n");



//Receive a message from client
while( 1 )  //    while( (read_size = recv(nsockfd , client_message , 4000 , 0)) != 0)
{
    //clearing buffer
    memset(client_message, 0, sizeof(client_message));

    //taking received message and printing it
    read_size = recv(nsockfd , client_message , 4000 , 0);
        printf( "%s", client_message);
        printf( "\n");

    //Send the message back to client
   // write(nsockfd , server_message , strlen(server_message));


    if (strcmp(client_message , "Hello")) // condition for project
    {
        write(nsockfd, friend_msg, strlen(friend_msg));
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me like you're calling recv on the client side way more often than you intended to.

Comment: Note that TCP/IP is streaming protocol. It does not have packets. That is, receiver does not necessarily receive data in same size chunks as sender sends it. You must add your own protocol on top of TCP/IP. It can simply be using something like newline to separate messages, or it can be sending data size, then sending that many bytes of data. And then you need buffering on the receiving end, so if you did not receive entire message, you wait for more data, until you have a complete message.

Comment: That was done for trouble shooting due to the client not receiving anything from the server. The server also doesn't receive anything from the client.

Answer (score 1):

When you call the system functions, always check for errors! Where relevant, also check for partial writes / receives. For example, when you have this line:

```
send(sockfd , message , strlen(message) , 0);
```

You should have something like this (untested, so think it through yourself):

(Edit: removed unnecessary resend loop to simplify code. See edit history if you want to see it...)

```
int msglen = strlen(message);
fprintf(stderr, "debug: about to send %d bytes", msglen);

int sent = send(sockfd , message , msglen , 0);

if (sent == -1) { // for each function, read docs for error result
    perror("send message");
    // do some error handling
} else if (sent < msglen) {
    fprintf(stderr, "debug: partial send %d/%d\n", sent, msglen);
    // do some disconnect handling
}
```

Once you have proper error reporing, and if you can't solve your problem with that, then update the question with this debug/error information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Server.c

```
while (1) {
    //---- ACCEPT connection ------------------------------------
    sa = accept(s, 0, 0);                  // block for connection request  
    if (sa < 0) {
        printf("accept error %ld ", WSAGetLastError() ); 
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        printf("connection accepted");
    }
/*  gets(buf);
    bytesSent = send( s, buf, 10, 0 ); 
    printf( "Bytes Sent: %ld \n", bytesSent );*/

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Socket is now set up and bound. Wait for connection and process it. 

    //---- RECV bytes --------------------------------------------
    bytesRecv = recv( sa, recvbuf, 10, 0 );
    err = WSAGetLastError( );// 10057 = A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) 
    if ( bytesRecv == 0 || bytesRecv == WSAECONNRESET ) {
      printf( "Connection Closed.\n");
      WSACleanup();
    }
    printf( "\nBytes Recv from Client: %s \n ", recvbuf );

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
//  if(bytesRecv != 0 || bytesRecv != WSAECONNRESET){

    bytesSent = send( sa, buf, 10, 0 ); 
    if(bytesSent == -1)
    {
        //break;
        puts("Error\n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf( "Bytes Sent: %ld \n", bytesSent );
    Sleep(1000);
    }
    closesocket( sa );
    }
```

Client.c

```
while(1) {
    //--- INITIALIZATION -----------------------------------
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 1, 1 );
    err = WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData );

    if ( err != 0 ) {
        printf("WSAStartup error %ld", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------

    //---- Build address structure to bind to socket.--------  
    target.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family Internet
    target.sin_port = htons (SERVER_PORT); //Port to connect on
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (IPAddress); //Target IP
    //--------------------------------------------------------


    // ---- create SOCKET--------------------------------------
    s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket error %ld" , WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return false; //Couldn't create the socket
    }  
    //---------------------------------------------------------


    //---- try CONNECT -----------------------------------------
    if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("connect error %ld", WSAGetLastError() );
        WSACleanup();
        return false; //Couldn't connect
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------

    //---- SEND bytes -------------------------------------------

    bytesSent = send( s, buf, 10, 0 );
    printf( "Bytes Sent: %ld \n", bytesSent );
    Sleep(1000);


    if((bytesRecv = recv( s, recvbuf, 10, 0 )) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("Socket Error");
        err = WSAGetLastError( );// 10057 = A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) 
    }
    else
    {
    if ( bytesRecv == 0 || bytesRecv == WSAECONNRESET ) {
      printf( "Connection Closed.\n");
      WSACleanup();
    }
    printf( "\nBytes Recv from Server: %s \n ", recvbuf );
    //closesocket( sa );
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    closesocket( s );
    WSACleanup();
    }
```

`The above code strictly for Windows.`